# Отменить добавление в BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть у меня объект BindingList и обрабатывается событие AddingNew, в котором новый объект передается в другую форму для детального описания. Там могут либо сохранить изменения (тогда этот объект добавится сам в BindingList и еще в базу запишется), либо отменить их, я это ловлю и в базу оно не записывается, но в BindingList попадает. Нашел метод CancelNew - не смог его нормально использовать. Не пойму, какой именно индекс передать. Пробовал 0, list.IndexOf(e.NewObject), list.Count и еще что-то очевидное - не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает хранить данный объект в каком-нибудь SelectedObject? Если изменения отменены, то делать:

```
BindingList.Remove(SelectedObject);
```

Comment: Remove удаляет, как я понял, "зафиксированный" (на msdn они так называются) элемент. Событие же AddingNew вызывается еще до фиксации. В это месте, где я хочу вставить эту строчку, в листе (в дебаге смотрел) вообще нет этой новой записи - вот я ее удалить и не знаю как.

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться event'ом event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged. И уже в нем удаляйте при помощи Remove. По идее должно помочь. Вполне возможно в ListChangedEventArgs содержится ссылка на добавленный объект, что позволяет его удалить при помощи Remove.